# Input on same line in Python

Tags: python

I have a problem with an output in Python

I'm trying to have an input in the form

```
2
1 10
2 20
```

2 being the number of tests and each line representing the number used by the function

To be able to have a single output, I'm storing the values in a tab in Python. The problem is that my tab doesn't have the correct values. Using the values given before, I have the following result when looking into the tab

```
1 2 20 5
```

Here's my code, thanks :

```
nbTest = input()
Tab = range(1,2*nbTest + 2)

for i in range(1,nbTest + 1):
  a,b = map(int,sys.stdin.readline().split())
  Tab[i] = a
  Tab[i+1] = b
  i = i + 1

print Tab[1], Tab[2], Tab[3], Tab[4]
```

Comment: What are you *expecting* in the `Tab`? Why are you only printing `Tab[1:5]`? Why are you using `input()` rather than `int(raw_input())`? Why are you both using a `for` loop **and** attempting to increment `i`? Are the `1` and `2` just the number of that input (and, if, so, why don't you include it in the prompt)?

Comment: 1) Expecting 1 10 2 20
2) What's the difference?
3) Mistake

Comment: Found my problem, solved.
Thanks anyway.

Comment: `Tab` is just a list. Or you could use a list-of-list, or list-of-tuple, or Queue-of-tuple, or whatever. You don't need to initialize its length, just declare `Tab = []`, then append to it as you go.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't have to "initialize" a list in python, so

```
Tab = range(1,2*nbTest + 2)
```

is unnecessary.

Second: the line

```
i = i + 1
```

doesn't do anything since the variable `i` is reassigned immediately afterwards.

Third: You should append tuples of values to your output list like this:

```py
nbTest = int(raw_input())
inputs = []

for i in range(0,nbTest):
    a,b = map(int, raw_input().split())
    inputs.append((a,b))

print nbTest
for el in inputs:
    print el[0], el[1]
```

Comment: These days, `map(fn, list)` can be replaced by list comprehension `[fn(x) for x in list]`

Answer (score 0):

Your should not modify the loop variable `i` inside the loop.
The line `i = i + 1` does nothing since `i` is reassigned by the `for` loop, so you overwrite the `Tab[i+1]` of the previous iteration with `Tab[i]`. If you want `i` to increase by 2 at each iteration use `range(1, nbTest+1, 2)` instead.

Also note that you don't have to initialise the size of your list, you can simply do `Tab=list()`, and then use `Tab += [a,b]`

Also, pythons arrays start at 0, so your range must be start from 0 as well. Otherwise the first slot of the list will not be replaced.

*Note* If you are using python3, you must do `Tab = list(range(1, 2*nbTest+2))` if you want `Tab` to be a list.